# How to convert string to color in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

How can I assign a custom color to any control from the script in unity?

This is how I am looking to assign?

```
 prefab.QuestionsToggle.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().color ="#f3f3f3";
```

Comment: Thank you @ Programmer, How to convert hex to Color(RGBA) with TryParseHtmlString ..this solved my issue.

Comment: You are welcome! I wasn't notified about your comment so I think I should tell you that you shouldn't add space between @ and the username if you want to notify another user.